# Merging multiple dataframes on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Using Pandas 1.2.1

MRE:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4], "B":[33, 44, 55, 66]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"B":[33, 44,99], "C":["v", "z", "z"]})
df_c = pd.DataFrame({"A":[3,4,77,55], "D":["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]})
```

Using three dfs created above I want to join all of them together however

1. df_a, df_b share column "B" therefore they join on column "B"
2. df_a, df_c share column "A" therefore they join on column "A"

I want to left_join df_b and df_c onto df_a. currently this is my method:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on=["B"], how="left")
merged_df = pd.merge(merged_df, df_c, on=["A"], how="left")
```

I know works fine however I cannot stop to think there is a easier and faster way, there are multiple questions on joining multiple dfs on same column using reduce function however could not find solution for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove `on` parameter, so it merging by intersection of columns names between DataFrames:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how="left")
merged_df = pd.merge(merged_df, df_c, how="left")
```

More dynamic is use `reduce`, also is removed `on` parameter:

```
from functools import reduce
dfList = [df1, df2, df3]
df = reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1,df2,how="left"), dfList)
```

Comment: The reason I added col name is because readability, is there an alternative way to do it with more readability?

Comment: @Ambleu - Hmmm, I think then need your solution, only remove `['A']` to `A`, similar for `B`

Comment: Could you clarify? not fully understanding it.

Comment: @Ambleu - It is only small changhe in your solution like `merged_df = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on=["B"], how="left")` to `merged_df = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on="B", how="left")`

Comment: Thanks! I am curious if there is similar method for joining columns however in this case joining columns to not share same name, in such case code like my example is cleanest it could be?

Comment: @Ambleu - I hope so ;)